# Set variable using HTML form - then compile

Tags: html, sass

Let's use a classing example: in a file, let's call it _example.scss, I have the following variables:

```
$color1
$color2
```

I was wondering if it is possible to create an html-form or some html-gui from which I can change (or set) the value assigned to those variables in that file?

Like using a color picker which will set those variables to a given value.

Answer (score 1):

the short answer is no, scss is a pre-processor.  both server(back-end) and browser(front-end) don't read scss at all.

so what you can do is use javascript/jquery to manipulate the value.

```
var style = $('input').value();
$('div').css({'color': style });
```

Comment: Hi, tnx for your answer. But the whole idea is to use html to set the values of the variables (just a GUI instead of editing the sass files), and afterwards compile the whole thing to a css file. So it shouldn't be at runtime or so. I'm just looking for some kind of html GUI that can be used to set the value of the vars inside the sass files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Sass parser in JavaScript which offers a API running a [Web Worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker). [sass.js](https://github.com/medialize/sass.js/) is a js library that offers these bindings.

Generally I wouldn't consider this good practice although do not have knowledge or you use case.